# How to check if 1 bit is off as compared to the expected number

Tags: c#, .net, bit-manipulation

I am checking a FAT systems table and need to determine if a 32 bit integer is off by one bit as compared to what is expected. Normally the listed location is +1 of the current location, unless a jump is needed due to another file in the way. If the disk is having corruption issues, the value is usually off by 1 bit being set outside of the norm. I have written how I am checking now, but would like to know if there is a simpler or fast manner to perform this function.

```
internal bool CheckFatValueToIndex(int expectedCluster, int recievedValue)
{
    /*Clear one bit and compare to expected value
     *Return true if expected cluster is 1 bit off*/
    if ((expectedCluster | 0x01) == recievedValue || (expectedCluster | 0x02) == recievedValue || (expectedCluster | 0x04) == recievedValue || (expectedCluster | 0x08) == recievedValue || (expectedCluster | 0x10) == recievedValue || (expectedCluster | 0x20) == recievedValue || (expectedCluster | 0x40) == recievedValue || (expectedCluster | 0x80) == recievedValue || (expectedCluster | 0x100) == recievedValue)
        return true;
    if ((expectedCluster | 0x200) == recievedValue || (expectedCluster | 0x400) == recievedValue || (expectedCluster | 0x800) == recievedValue || (expectedCluster | 0x1000) == recievedValue || (expectedCluster | 0x2000) == recievedValue || (expectedCluster | 0x4000) == recievedValue || (expectedCluster | 0x8000) == recievedValue)
        return true;

        return false;
}
```

Comment: Can't you XOR the two values together, and if the result is a power of 2 then it's 1 bit off?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all you need to extract changed bits, this can be simply done with [XOR](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bitwise_operations_in_C):

```
expectedCluster ^ receivedValue
```

Each set bit represents a difference: if bits are the same (0 or 1) result is 0 but it's 1 if they differ.

Now you have to count them. You can use [Hamming](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hamming_weight) algorithm:

```
int CountSetBits(int x) {
    int count = 0;
    for (count = 0; x > 0; ++count)
        x &= x - 1;

    return count;
}
```

You can then check it:

```
return CountSetBits(expectedCluster ^ receivedValue) > 1;
```

Edit: Quantic suggested to check if XORed number is a power of 2, if you do not need to count how many *corrupted*/changed bits you have then this should be faster (if you care):

```
bool IsPowerOf2(int x) {
    return x != 0 && (x & (x - 1)) == 0;
}
```